# Dagger dependency injection - how to inject 2 objects where one depends on another?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dagger

I am still pretty new to dagger dependency injection and can't figure out a way to do this.
I have 2 objects, `ExecutorService` and `CompletionService` that I want to inject into my module, where `CompletionService` is dependent on the other. I want to dependency inject both to be able to mock `CompletionService`'s `.take()` method in my tests and I need the same `ExecutorService` to be able to shutdown the threadpool.

I want to dependency inject Java's `ExecutorService` and `CompletionService` into the same object where one depends on the other:

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
CompletionService<List<String>> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executorService);
```

It would look like the following:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
ExecutorService provideExecutorService() {
    return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
CompletionService<List<String>> provideExecutorCompletionService() {
    return new ExecutorCompletionService<>(provideExecutorService());
}

//Inject into parent object

@Provides
@Singleton
Foo provideFoo(final executorService, final executorCompletionService) {
    return new Foo(executorService, executorCompletionService);
}
```

However, the `executorService` instantiated within `executorCompletionService` is not the same as the one passed into `Foo`, and thus later on when calling `executorService.shutdown()`, on the executorService it doesn't shutdown the threadpool on executorCompletionService. Is there a way to make sure the executorService passed into CompletionService is the same as Foo?